# Remove class from element when click outside the Dropdown - Angular

Tags: angular, dom, directive

I’m working on a dropdown, with different sublists inside, I’m trying to close the dropdown when I click in a different part of the page, basically anywhere but in the menu. The css class show-list should be remove if I click anywhere in the page. And if I have an open menu and try to open a different one, the other should close. And I don’t know how, I tried with different things but nothing seems to work.

[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sih622?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu%2Fmenu.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu%2Fmenu.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu%2Fmenu.directive.ts)

This html structure is meant to be reusable, so I created a directive file:

**Directive file**

```
// If the click was inside the menu, toggle show-list
        if (menu.contains(clickedElement)) {
          this.childSelector.forEach((selector) => {
            const childMenus = parentLi.querySelectorAll(selector);
            childMenus.forEach((childMenu: Element) => {
              this.toggleMenu(childMenu, isButtonClicked);
            });
          });
        } else {
          // If the click was outside the menu, remove show-list from all menu levels
          this.removeAllShowListClasses(menu);
        }
      toggleMenu(menu: any, showSubList: boolean) {
        if (showSubList) {
          if (menu.classList.contains('show-list')) {
            this.renderer.removeClass(menu, 'show-list');
          } else {
            this.renderer.addClass(menu, 'show-list');
          }
        }
      }

      removeAllShowListClasses(element: Element) {
        const allChildrenWithShowList = element.querySelectorAll('.show-list');
        allChildrenWithShowList.forEach((child) =>
          this.renderer.removeClass(child, 'show-list')
        );
      }
```

**Html structure**

```
<div Menu>
    <button>List Item</button>
    <ul>More code</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to uncomment this line `franklinMenuButtonGroup.classList.remove('menu-display-animation');`?

Comment: Yes haha .That line of code works but not entirely because if you tried for example, open a sublist, the dropdown close and it shouldn't suppose to do that.